# How to fill subcategories based on category selection in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have JSON data like this:

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "abc",
    "image": "abc.png",
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "scid": "1",
            "scname": "abc1"
        },
        {
            "scid": "2",
            "scname": "abc2"
        },
        {
            "scid": "3",
            "scname": "abc3"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "xyz",
    "image": "xyz.png",
    "subcategories": [
        {
            "scid": "4",
            "scname": "xyz1"
        },
        {
            "scid": "5",
            "scname": "xyz2"
        },
        {
            "scid": "6",
            "scname": "xyz3"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

and trying to fill categories and subcategories like this:

```
            <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <TD>Category Name</TD>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="NewProduct.category" ng-options="category as category.name for category in Categories | orderBy:['name']" required></select>
                    </td>   
                </div>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <TD>Sub Category Name</TD>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="NewProduct.subcategory" ng-options="subcategory as subcategory.name for subcategory in Categories.subcategories | orderBy:['scname'] | filter:{ 'id' : NewProduct.category.id }:true" required></select>
                    </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
```

Though categories are filling well, but no sub-categories are getting filled, after selecting category.

Can anyone help me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second ng-options you say:

```
subcategory as subcategory.name for subcategory in Categories.subcategories
```

But `Categories` looks like it is probably an array, so won't have a `.subcategories` property.  Instead I think you meant to use the category from your ngModel on the first select.

```
ng-model="NewProduct.category"
```

This would leave you with:

```
subcategory as subcategory.name for subcategory in NewProduct.category.subcategories
```